# Monit "is alive" check of PostgreSQL tends to fail during a run of pg_dump, is there a better way?

Tags: postgresql, monit, backup, psql

I use pg_dump for my primary backup, once every three hours.  I also use monit.  When monit checks if PostgreSQL is alive during the pg_dump run, it sometimes times out, and restarts postgres.  This results in failed backup.

What to do?  Move to Write-Ahead-Logs?  Disable monit during the backup?  The database is serving an active web site at these times.

Monit config.:

```
check process postgres with pidfile /usr/local/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid
group database
start program = "/etc/init.d/postgresql start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/postgresql stop"
if failed unixsocket /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 protocol pgsql then restart
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 5432      protocol pgsql then restart
if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Comment: What does your monit configuration look like?  Can you simply configure it to be a bit more relaxed? So instead of immediately restarting if the services is not alive, maybe it should wait for a few cycles of being in a failed state?

Answer (score 2):

So something like this?

```
if failed unixsocket /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 protocol pgsql for 5 cycles then restart
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 5432      protocol pgsql for 5 cycles then restart
if 5 restarts within 25 cycles then timeout
```

That way the monit check would have to unreachable for 15 minutes before a restart.  Assuming a 180 second cycle interval.  Obviously you can adjust to your tastes, but resetting after a single failed check can result in false positives if your server happens to be busy or otherwise occupied.

Comment: Thanks for this. pg_dump is probably the wrong tool for the job, but it's easiest for now.  Will try loosening monit and see if that prevents a restart.  The web application appears to be fine during these periods.